how to connect 12VDC driver for LED shelf lights
how to connect 12VDC driver for LED shelf lights
In an attempt to keep both outlets open for future use, I'm looking for ideas on how to connect a 12vdc driver to power
to a PIR sensor and some LED shelf lights (all 12vdc).
Including a picture to help.
During construction, the conduit (on the right, painted to match the shelf) was installed.
That conduit connects to the outlet (on the left).
I don't suppose I can just put an electrical box at the open end of the conduit, run 14/2 from the outlet through the conduit to the box and wire the driver direct in the box?


aside: PIR probably isn't the best match for the location as they work best for places briefly occupied (hall, coat closet, etc). Look for mmWave aka "presence" sensors so that the light doesn't turn off while your siting there and catch they eye or make you flail your arms like a baboon to re-light.

Yup, agreed.  I have one, wasn't sure which sensor I was going to use for this.
Appreciated.

If you can get a proper junction box properly mounted to the end of the conduit and fixed firmly to the cabinet, and you can then run correct wiring to the existing outlet through the conduit, then you could put an outlet in the new junction box. NM ("romex") cable can be used, and the conduit looks wide enough to allow one piece of NM cable in it. The rules on conduit fill say that NM cable has to count as a round cable of the same diameter as the widest dimension of the NM cable. If your conduit can take a round cable as wide as the NM cable, then you could put NM in the conduit. Or you can get a few feet of black, white, and green/bare THHN wires.
You would not be allowed to put the driver inside the junction box along with the high voltage house power, unless the driver were UL/ETL listed and had instructions for installing the driver inside a junction box, with manufacturer-provided means for allowing the low voltage LED drive wiring out of the junction box.
Low voltage and high voltage cannot mix inside a junction box, unless the device is designed to have an access point mountable in a hole of the junction box for low voltage to come out. Some devices, like doorbell transformers and certain relays, have a place to mount the device to the junction box in a knockout, and pass the high voltage through the knockout to the device. If your device doesn't have instructions on how to do this, then you cannot jerry-rig it and be code compliant.

Thank you for the information.
Doing research on how to best accomplish this and I have one additional question.
If I were to get a metal handy box and mount it on the bottom of the cabinet with the opening for the outlet on the top (face up if that makes any sense).  Would that be code compliant or does the handy box need to be mounted in a different way?  I would remove one of the knockouts on the back and use a male adapter to attach the PVC conduit, and screw the handy box to the cabinet.

@unruly1 That's a good question. I'm not sure of code requirements in that case. Outlets can face up, they can be mounted in floors. I am not sure if a metal junction box with knockouts can be mounted in an accessible location: some child may push in a knockout during play. Aesthetically, I'd lean toward a plastic surface-mount box, or build a wood surround for a metal box. I You may want to ask a new question about the face-up mounting of a metal handy box.
